# A problem occurred configuring project ':shared_preferences_android'

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

I was trying to use this dependency but the problem is that my terminal couldn't access the directory due to my user name. I have a school organization account, and after the name it has a "(St" after my name. I tried to cd into that directory but it tells me that is requires a "close parentheses" or ")". How can I fix this?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':shared_preferences_android'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':shared_preferences_android:classpath'.
> Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\BoneteJobertJanne(St.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.97\descriptors\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.5.31\a8be1fe3b3911d3d3425fe720cf42835\descriptor.bin

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':shared_preferences_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':shared_preferences_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.